# How to change the page layout dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on job portal project using angular in which i wanted to change the page layout dynamically.
i have following menus "all,ID,A and FD" (menus are dynamic , user can add more menus from the backend) if i click on "ID" then i want the page layout color should be "orange", if i click on "A" then i want the page layout color should be "blue" ,and if i click on "FD" then i want the page layout color should be "red" if further user can add the new menu these layout should be repeat in same pattern.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-style` something like

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.items=[{ name:'all',color:'none'},{ name:'ID',color:'orange'},{ name:'A',color:'blue'},{ name:'FD',color:'red'}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-style="{ 'background-color': selected.color }">
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in items " ng-model="selected"></select>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer....but the menus are not fixed....in future $scope.items = ['all','ID','A','FD','3D']....if '3D' selected i want the layout color orange

Comment: @Priyanka then you have to attach color attribute with your menu list Check updated answer

Comment: @Priyanka glad to help you